# Phaser Screen goes black without errors

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

Yesterday I was working on a small prototype and everything was going well.

This morning I tried launching it again, using Chrome as usual, and I see the game screen for a second but then the screen goes black. After that I only see a black screen for every phaser game that is hosted on localhost when using Chrome.

Phaser games hosted elsewhere still work, and I can still play games on localhost if I use Firefox or IE, it's just Chrome that bugs after playing a specific prototype, and kinda blocks Phaser from running on localhost... Whenever I restart my computer, I can run Phaser games on Chrome again, but when I run this specific prototype I see it for a second and then every game on localhost goes black again...

I'm trying to find out what went wrong with my prototype, as it was working normally till now. Any ideas?

Thanks,

-- UPDATE --

I commented my entire prototype to investigate what was causing the problem, and started uncommenting it block by block, testing every part of it.

I now have my entire prototype working again as before, even though no changes were made to the code.

Could it possibly be a problem with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with my chrome (Still no idea why) on a few projects.

The only thing I can input is by ( if you are not already ) using brackets text editor that links with chrome, since making this switch I have had any random game crashes.

EDIT: Just read through through that again, im not sure with typescript sorry, this issue was with JS, however here a git link to a brackets typescript add in

https://github.com/fdecampredon/brackets-typescript

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio, I can't see why it would make a difference